# make file, what is the idea behind coining of special variables as described below

Tags: syntax, makefile

In make file, for one example, $@ is the name of the file being generated,

Find it difficult to remember these special variables

Is there a systematic way that this been coined?
or How this can be remembered?

Comment: The trick is to not write Makefiles by hand.  Use Cmake or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really need is a cheat-sheet. There are plenty available (search for makefile cheat sheet , and maybe specify the variant, eg gnu).

As an example: http://www.cheatography.com/bavo-van-achte/cheat-sheets/gnumake/

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no mnemonic that I can think of.  The list of automatic variables is [documented here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html).  There are really only three that are typically used, so they're not that hard to remember once you get used to them: `$@` for the target, `$<` for the first prerequisite, and `$^` for all the prerequisites.  The others are more for special situations.